# Are there any significant disadvantages of using python modules for configuration?

Tags: python, configuration

For my last few programs I have used python config files of this style

```
key="value"

contacts = [
    {
         "name": "Herbert",
         "age": 10,
         "height": "120cm"
    },
    {
         "name": "Knight",
         "age": 100,
         "height": "200in"
    }
]
```

This means I can just access the config like this:

```
import config
value = config.key
for person in config.contacts:
    do_thing(person["name"], age=person["age"])
```

you could also do fancy stuff like using the installed address book program, or other things that decide the config at runtime.

```
from address_book_interface_module import people.dump_all

key = "value"

contacts = people.dump_all()
```

with a bit more work, you could also allow people to write functions

```
from address_book_interface_module import people.dump_all

def key():
    if condition:
        return "value"
    else:
        return "toast"

contacts = people.dump_all()
```

From my perspective, this is an unbeatable amount of configuration and possibilities, essentially allowing you to write fully functional extensions in your config file.

Yet, these config files are nearly never used. In another SO question, this was dismissed as "insecure", yet Django and the "awesome window manager" (it uses Lua) use this with no issues.

*What are the disadvantages of these configuration files, that are significant enough that nobody uses them?*

Comment: First of all programmers do use them, Second it basically opinion based question, I'm preferring YAML or JSON for config files, Also a simple `cfg` file will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an approach (in any language that allows it) is insecure because a user who edits the configuration file can add arbitrary commands, such as commands to delete files.

Many years ago, when I first started using the Tcl scripting language, Tcl books advocated a similar approach (that is, applications should use Tcl as the syntax in their configuration files). I hated this approach because an application's users might not be familiar with Tcl syntax, and if a user made a typo in what they thought was a configuration file, then they would be surprised to see a stack trace rather than a user-friendly error message.

Another issue is that some configuration-file parsers have schema validation engines that can automate error checking of the contents of a configuration file. For example, there are [numerous schema validation languages for XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_schemas), there is now a [schema validation language for JSON](http://json-schema.org/), and [Config4*](http://www.config4star.org/) (a configuration parser developed by me) also has its own [schema validator](http://www.config4star.org/config4star-getting-started-guide/overview-of-the-config4star-api.html#sect:intro:prog-api:schema-validation). In contrast, your example Python programs neglect to validate the configuration data before attempting use that data. So if a user enters syntactically correct but semantically incorrect data in a Python-based configuration file, then the result is likely to be a program crash at an arbitrary point in the program's execution rather than an informative error message.